# How to determine what user applications are running e.g. chrome, word, spotify in C++

Tags: c++, windows, process

I want to be able to view a list of what user applications are currently running. (that you would open yourself e.g. spotify chrome, safari) Ideally I can find this information in C and then save what applications the user has open.

Essentially when you open task manager I need the list of applications that is separate from the background processes. Being that the task manager separates these, there has to be a fundamental difference between these kinds of processes is my line of reasoning. However, I haven't been able to find anything.

I've searched WMIC for anything helpful but could not find any useful information in PROCESS LIST and really this was my only lead.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Some info here, from the master himself: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606

Comment: Ha, Thank you! This makes me wonder if I could just find a list of visible windows.

Comment: [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) might be a good place to start.